# Connect Office Web Apps Farm to multiple SharePoint Farms

Tags: office-web-apps

Is it possible to connect a single office web apps farm to multiple SharePoint farms, or a 1 to 1 relationship is a requirement for it to work?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a single Office Web Apps farm can be connected to multiple SharePoint farms, just configure the farms in the usual way, then link them to the Office Web Apps farm using the New-SPWOPIBinding command from each SharePoint farm.